# jQuery .each loop failing - getting data from HTML objects and parsing to .append

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, each

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

---

[This is what the end result should look like...](http://jsfiddle.net/49kg9/10/)

---

- find all `.section` elements inside of `.tabbed`
- for each `.section-title` found `.section` of `.tabbed`, *do this*

**Which is basically (Code Updated)**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {   
  t = $('.tabbed');
  s = $('.section');
  ss = $('.sub-section');   
  st = $('.section-title');
   x = $(this);   

$(t).find(s).each(function(i, section) {
  $(section).find(st).each(function(i2, title) {
    name = $(title).text();         
    url = $(section).attr('id');
    t.append('<ul id="list"></ul>');
    $('#list').html('<li><a href="#'+url+'">'+name+'</a></li>');    
  });
});
t.tabs();
})
```

*The* `<li>` *elements are created using the* `.section` `id` *as an* `<a href""></a>` *where the link contains the* `.section-title` *text.*

I have put together a  [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/49kg9/7/). I'm still misunderstanding something about `.each` I guess.

**Left actual code in jsfiddle to keep post neat.*

Comment: IDs must be unique. `section` in your code is a DOM element object not a jQuery object, jQuery object doesn't have `innerHTML` method, use `html` method.

Comment: I've changed your fiddle by little, http://jsfiddle.net/49kg9/4/

Comment: Very ambiguous question, could you clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I noticed you tried to use 'find' method on an object passed as an argument to 'each' method's callback function, which won't work because 'each' method 'feeds' that callback with html elements. So you'd need to make them a jQuery object first. In your case: $(section).find(...) instead of just section.find(...)

Comment: Sorry went out for lunch. I'm trying to gather all `.section-titles` into a jQuery created `<ul id="list">` as `<li>` with `<a>`. I thought I was being thorough.

Comment: The ID is only on the `#list` `<ul>`. There is only one. The rest are classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?
I fixed the looping through the elements as you weren't actually referring to the element which is actually selected but selecting the elements by their classes. To select the element currently being worked on in the each loop use `$(this)`

Here's an updated fiddle, hope that helps - http://jsfiddle.net/49kg9/5/

Comment: That's somewhat right but why isn't it grabbing the first section? I'm trying to use this with jQueryUI's `tabs()`

Comment: I feel silly that I didn't notice this previously - the code is appending an element on each loop, thus overwriting the previously created html. This code fixes it, please refer to jQuery documentation for explanations on the functions - http://jsfiddle.net/friiks/49kg9/9/

Comment: Thank you, that looks so much neater. I'll check out `.log`. (btw, append should be prepend, my mistake)

Comment: Hey, just noticed the `id` `list` is outside of the each loop. How can I make it `list-1` where 1 is the index of the `.tabbed`? There may be multiple tabbed sections